# how to do Prisma soft delete with NestJS?

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I had tried to implement this method in my application. but I don't have depth knowledge of Prisma. Kindly explain that with some examples.

Comment: What do you mean by `soft delete`? Once data in Prisma is deleted, it's permanently deleted. There is no concept of a soft delete unless you implement it at the database level. Please see the Stack Overflow "How to Ask" guide for how to ask a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @SheaHunterBelsky, it is a good question. In fact, there is documentation for it. Don't judge people too quickly!
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware/soft-delete-middleware

Comment: This comment was a year ago - My original comment meant to say that Prisma doesn't have this functionality, and it had to be added. At the time of my original comment, that documentation did not exist!

Comment: I found this package which handles more things https://github.com/olivierwilkinson/prisma-soft-delete-middleware?tab=readme-ov-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a middleware to mark a question as a deleted instead of actually deleting it.

`schema.prisma`

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model Post {
  id      Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title   String
  content String?
  user    User?   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId  Int?
  tags    Tag[]
  views   Int     @default(0)
  deleted Boolean @default(false)
}
```

Here a field called deleted is added to the Post model.

Middleware performs the following operation:

- Intercepts delete and deleteMany queries for the Post model
- Changes the params.action to update and updateMany respectively
- Introduces a data argument and sets `{ deleted: true }`, preserving other filter arguments if they exist

`script.ts`

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient({})

async function main() {
  /***********************************/
  /* SOFT DELETE MIDDLEWARE */
  /***********************************/

  prisma.$use(async (params, next) => {
    // Check incoming query type
    if (params.model == 'Post') {
      if (params.action == 'delete') {
        // Delete queries
        // Change action to an update
        params.action = 'update'
        params.args['data'] = { deleted: true }
      }
      if (params.action == 'deleteMany') {
        // Delete many queries
        params.action = 'updateMany'
        if (params.args.data != undefined) {
          params.args.data['deleted'] = true
        } else {
          params.args['data'] = { deleted: true }
        }
      }
    }
    return next(params)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

with depracation of middleware now its done by using extensions, you can check this article I wrote https://medium.com/@erciliomarquesmanhica/implementing-soft-delete-in-prisma-using-client-extensions-a-step-by-step-guide-for-nestjs-51a9d0716831 but here is short version of it:

**Step 1: Setting up Prisma**

I assume you already did this, if not please follow this docs [Prisma on Nestjs](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/prisma).

**Step 2: Adding Soft Delete Field**

Now that we have Prisma configured, we need to add the flag property on our models, this can be a boolean or date, usually people use date to also store when it was deleted. so in this step we will add the property deleted_at.

**Step 3: Implementing Soft Delete Logic**

So if your did the step one correctly you endup with a PrismaService , so in order to add that soft delete logic to our prisma service we used to use middlwares, but it is depracated now, and we are currently doing it by adding client extensions .

So lets create those extensions then:

Create a file to hold your prisma extensions can call it prisma.extensions.ts

```
 import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';
    
    //extension for soft delete
    export const softDelete = Prisma.defineExtension({
      name: 'softDelete',
      model: {
        $allModels: {
          async delete<M, A>(
            this: M,
            where: Prisma.Args<M, 'delete'>['where'],
          ): Promise<Prisma.Result<M, A, 'update'>> {
            const context = Prisma.getExtensionContext(this);
    
            return (context as any).update({
              where,
              data: {
                deleted_at: new Date(),
              },
            });
          },
        },
      },
    });
    
    //extension for soft delete Many
    export const softDeleteMany = Prisma.defineExtension({
      name: 'softDeleteMany',
      model: {
        $allModels: {
          async deleteMany<M, A>(
            this: M,
            where: Prisma.Args<M, 'deleteMany'>['where'],
          ): Promise<Prisma.Result<M, A, 'updateMany'>> {
            const context = Prisma.getExtensionContext(this);
    
            return (context as any).updateMany({
              where,
              data: {
                deleted_at: new Date(),
              },
            });
          },
        },
      },
    });
    
    //extension for filtering soft deleted rows from queries
    export const filterSoftDeleted = Prisma.defineExtension({
      name: 'filterSoftDeleted',
      query: {
        $allModels: {
          async $allOperations({ model, operation, args, query }) {
            if (
              operation === 'findUnique' ||
              operation === 'findFirst' ||
              operation === 'findMany'
            ) {
              args.where = { ...args.where, deleted_at: null };
              return query(args);
            }
            return query(args);
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

These are pretty self explanatory extensions, if you are having problems understanding them I recommend you to go ready the docs [client extensions](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/client-extensions), its pretty straight forward.

**Step 4: Adding the extension to Prisma Service**

So this step can be a little bit confusing. why you would ask!

First by intuition you will be tempeted to just go on PrismaService and add the extensions like this:

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClientExtended } from './custom-prisma-client';
import {
  filterSoftDeleted,
  softDelete,
  softDeleteMany,
} from './prisma.extension';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService
  extends PrismaClient 
  implements OnModuleInit
{
  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
    this.$extends(softDelete) //adding extensions
      .$extends(softDeleteMany)
      .$extends(filterSoftDeleted);
  }
}
```

And I dont blame you, I first did it like this, and didnt work, why? because you need to add the extensions explicitly to the client. if its not clear dont worry, you will get it as we go.

So how do we actually add the extensions to the Prisma Service?

We will add the extension to PrismaService by extending a CustomPrismaClient of ours, which already has the extensions added. what I mean by that is that we will create a CustomPrismaClient and then extend it on our PrismaService.

So first lets create the CustomPrismaClient. create a file, can call it custom-prisma-client.ts and add these code:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import {
  filterSoftDeleted,
  softDelete,
  softDeleteMany,
} from './prisma.extension';

//function to give us a prismaClient with extensions we want
export const customPrismaClient = (prismaClient: PrismaClient) => {
  return prismaClient
    .$extends(softDelete) //here we add our created extensions
    .$extends(softDeleteMany)
    .$extends(filterSoftDeleted);
};

//Our Custom Prisma Client with the client set to the customPrismaClient with extension
export class PrismaClientExtended extends PrismaClient {
  customPrismaClient: CustomPrismaClient;

  get client() {
    if (!this.customPrismaClient)
      this.customPrismaClient = customPrismaClient(this);

    return this.customPrismaClient;
  }
}

//Create a type to our funtion
export type CustomPrismaClient = ReturnType<typeof customPrismaClient>;
```

So I tried to add comments for increase your understanding, but basically we are creating a helper function that given a prismaClient it returns us that prismaClient with our extensions. and then we use that function on our PrismaClientExtended to set extensions.

WIth that done, now all we need to do is extend our PrismaClientExtended class on PrismaService:

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClientExtended } from './custom-prisma-client';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService
  extends PrismaClientExtended // we now extending PrismaClientExtended
  implements OnModuleInit
{
  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
  }
}
```

**Step 5: How to use it?**

Well, I am adding this step because if you are like me, all my queries where done in some way that would no work with extensions, let me show you:

```
remove(id: number): Promise<any> {
  return this.prismaService.posts.delete({
    where: {
      id: id,
    },
  });
}
```

so this usually works fine, but remember we added our extensions to the client of our prismaService, thats why we need to use the client, and if you look closely the parameters already expects the where object, that why you send the object directy.

```
remove(id: number): Promise<any> {
  return this.prismaService.client.posts.delete({
      id: id,
  });
}
```

compare these two closely, many people will rush these step and fail.

the same goes to the deleteMany method:

```
removeAllPostsByUserId(id: number): Promise<any> {
  return this.prismaService.client.posts.deleteMany({
    user_id: id,
  });
}
```

and for the rest of queries you just need to use client, like this:

```
findAll(): Promise<Posts[]> {
  return this.prismaService.client.posts.findMany({
    include: { comments: true },
  });
}
```